# C# RDLC reporting get value of row1 column in row2

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, reportviewer, rdlc

```
id    name         debit     credit    balance
1     umer         100         0         100
2     umer          0         50          50
3     umer          0         10          40
4     umer          200        0         240
```

i want result like this in c# rdlc report. while i am only getting first four columns from database "Balance" column i have to make my self in report can anyone guide me how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got not much help. i select data with this query

```
SELECT id, name, debit, credit, debit - credit as balance FROM Balance
```

and then in report balance column i add this

```
=Previous(RunningValue(Fields!balance.Value,sum,nothing))+Fields!balance.Value
```

and i got my desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer depends on what mechanism you are using to bind elements in the report to. How are you fetching your data? Is this  a datatable?

Regardless, as a general rule, the answer to your question is independent of RDLC, and You should be calculating the value of this column before you get to the report. So if you're binding report elements to the results of a SQL call, you'd add a calculated column to your query:

```
SELECT id, name, debit, credit, debit - credit as balance
FROM Balance
```

If you're binding your report elements to classes, just add a property to that class and calculate the value for each item after the objects are populated

Comment: yes it is a database. but i need to add first row balance in 2nd row. read the balance column carefully please. and thanks for reply

Comment: can u suggest any good tutorial series for rdlc reporting for me?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but you still haven't said how you're getting from the database to the report specifically: what type is your Dataset?. My question was whether you are using a DataTable object or some other mechanism. I think what you need to do may be better suited to C# than to SQL, but without knowing anything about what you're already doing, further guidance is difficult.

Comment: can u please tell me how to get value of a dynamicly added clumns. like i can get value of my dataset field by [debit] how to get value of a self created column?